# Как добавить элемент в array?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не понимаю? Как добавить элемент в array?

```
object = {
        array: []
}
```

так ошибка: `object[array].push(500)`

так тоже ошибка: `object[array][0] = 500`

А как иначе то еще?
Ведь если array это массив `array = [];` То в него можно ведь добавить элементы вот так: `array.push(500)`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
object.array.push(500)
```

"object" это объект(простите за тавтологию), а доступ к полям объекта осуществляется через точку.

Comment: Благодарю! действительно

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется использовать скобочную нотацию, то ключ надо записывать как строку. В ином случае интерпретатор ищет объявленную переменную с именем `array`

```
object['array'].push(500);
```

Но в целом в объектах, как правило, к ключам обращаются через точку

```
object.array.push(500)
```

Просто есть исключительные ситуации, когда через точку обратиться не получится и используются скобки.